# Battery draining whenever the headlights come on

Tags: toyota, camry, battery-drain

My car (2001 Toyota Camry) drives fine as long as the headlights are not on. As soon as it gets dark and the automatic headlights come on the battery light comes on and my car dies. What's going on? I had the battery tested and its good. New alternator also.

Comment: check user manual and see if the light is on because of overload/ over discharge or because it is out of charge

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

Answer (score 3):

2001 toyota camry. Turns out the brand new alternator was bad. Just my luck. So I had to replace it again and get the battery recharged. Thanks